# fontManager = Error while trying to run Matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Matplotlib beginner code below is not getting executed. I tried code from the User Guide of the Matplotlib site. Python Shell is returning error.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])<br>
plt.xlabel('X LABEL')<br>
plt.ylabel('Y LABEL')<br>
plt.show()
```

What is the actual Problem? I'm a beginner to Python

### ERROR

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1353, in 
    `fontManager = json_load(_fmcache)`
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 889, in json_load
    `return json.load(fh, object_hook=_json_decode)`
  File "D:\Python\lib\json__init__.py", line 296, in load
    `parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook,**kw)`
  File "D:\Python\lib\json__init__.py", line 361, in loads
    `return cls(**kw).decode(s)`
  File "D:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    `obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())`
  File "D:\Python\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    `obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)`
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 2165 column 60 (char 55240)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/1.py", line 1, in 
    `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 32, in 
    `import matplotlib.colorbar`
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 32, in
 
    `import matplotlib.contour as contour`
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 18, in 
    `import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager`
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1363, in 
    `_rebuild()`
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1347, in _rebuild
    `with cbook._lock_path(_fmcache)`:
  File "D:\Python\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in **enter**
    `return next(self.gen)`
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook__init__.py", line 1857, in _lock_path
    lock_path))
TimeoutError: Lock error: Matplotlib failed to acquire the following lock file:
    C:\Users\mypc.matplotlib\fontlist-v300.json.matplotlib-lock
This maybe due to another process holding this lock file.
  If you are sure no
other Matplotlib process is running, remove this file and try again.

Comment: Please, avoid saying "not getting executed", rather, show us what error is showing and the most recent callstacks

Comment: I have added the errors. Now how to solve the problem?